# bind_param() doesn't get executed

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem with prepared statements on mysqli and php.

I have a form where users can change their email address but it seems there’s a problem with bind_param(‘si’, $value, $value);

I’ve already tried different things to fix it but nothing has worked so far.
I hope you can spot the error.

**EDIT:**

Because of some discussion in the comments some additional information:

- I've already tried many things to solve the problem.
- No errors with try catch, no errors with error_reporting
- bind_param() doesn't do anything, it just jumps out of the code. Everything after bind_param() isn't executed
- Further tests have shown that $ustmt is NULL, thanks to @Vijay Dohare

HTML Form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="emailReset" id="emailReset" class="form-reset">
  <input type="hidden" name="UID" id="UID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

  <label class="reset-label sr-only" for="newEmail">Neue E-Mail-Adresse</label>
  <input name="newEmail" id="newEmail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Neue E-Mail-Adresse" required /><br />

  <label class="login-label sr-only" for="verifyEmail">E-Mail-Adresse wiederholen</label>
  <input name="verifyEmail" id="verifyEmail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse wiederholen" required /><br />

  <button name="emailReset" id="emailReset" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> E-Mail-Adresse &auml;ndern</button>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['emailReset'])) {
        $UID = intval($_POST['UID']);
        $newEmail = $_POST['newEmail'];
        $verifyEmail = $_POST['verifyEmail'];

        echo nl2br($UID . "\n");
        echo nl2br($newEmail . "\n");
        echo nl2br($verifyEmail . "\n");

        if($newEmail == $verifyEmail) {
            $emailsEqual = true;
            $escapedNewEmail = escape($newEmail);

            echo nl2br('' . "\n");
            echo nl2br('EscNewEmail: ' . $escapedNewEmail . "\n");
            echo nl2br('' . "\n");

            $ustmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE users SET Email = ? WHERE ID = ?');
            echo nl2br(is_null($con) ? 'Con, no.' : 'Con, yes' . "\n");
            echo nl2br(empty($con) ? 'Con, no.' : 'Con, yes' . "\n");
            $ustmt->bind_param('si', $escapedNewEmail, $UID); //DOESN'T WORK!!!
            $ustmt->execute();

            $affectedRows = $ustmt->affected_rows;

            if($affectedRows > 0) {
                $updated = true;
                echo nl2br($affectedRows . ' Rows affected.' . "\n");
            } else {
                $updated = false;
                echo nl2br($affectedRows . ' Rows affected.' . "\n");
          }

          $ustmt->close();  
      } else {
          $passwordsEqual = false;
      }
  }
```

Output:

```
value from UID
value from email
value from email

EscNewEmail: escaped value from email

Con, yes
Con, yes
```

Comment: So you are using `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*`?

Comment: @Justinas you should read the very first sentence again...

Comment: `Does not work` is NOT a proper description of a problem. Please provide a **reproducable** example and a proper description. This question in this form is off-topic (Why isn't this code working?). Since the function in question is working properly for the rest of the world, this question is the result of pure laziness. StackOverflow is **not a debugging service**.

Comment: Try `$ustmt->bind_param('ss', $escapedNewEmail, $UID);` and remove `intval()` for `$_POST['UID']`

Comment: @Pred
I've tried a sh*t ton of things, if I knew why the code isn't working, I wouldn't had asked the question.....
No errors with try catch, no errors with error_reporting, absolutly nothing.

Comment: @rhavendc I've also tried that, no effect.

Comment: @Taminoful If you don't see any changes with the `UPDATE` maybe there's an error occuring before it. Where exactly the `UID` value came from when you're executing `<?php echo $id; ?>`?

Comment: Yes, first line says `mysqli` but tagged as `mysql`

Comment: Maybe you've tried things, share them with us. You are still failing to describe your problem. Again: `Does not work` is not a proper description. Do you get any error messages? ***Is your error reporting on?***

Comment: @Pred please read my previous comment again...
I already stated that there are no errors messages with try catch and error_reporting..

Exclusively for you: 
bind_param() doesn't do anything, it just jumps out of the code. Everything after bind_param() isn't executed.

Comment: Try removing all white space around the question marks in your query like this: `'UPDATE users SET Email=? WHERE ID=?'`. Also check if `$ustmt` is `NULL` or 'FALSE`. Finally enable error reporting and post any errors or warnings

Comment: So this information is missing from your post, because? If the code stops at a line, it means a fatal error or an uncaught exception. Are you sure, that the `prepare()` is success and the `$ustmt` is a statement object?

Comment: Is this silence means that we can close this question?

Comment: @Pred this silence means that I'm not online all day, srly...
If you can't add something constructive to my question, please don't comment it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may check your database connection with following code

```
echo nl2br($con->connect_errno ? 'Con, no.' : 'Con, yes' . "\n");
```

because a false value will be returned by the connection if something wrong with the connection

i considered you are making connection to db like

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
```

Comment: Connection is set up with the following code
`try {
 $con = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME);
 $con->set_charset($CHARSET);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }`

Comment: plesae try `var_dump($ustmt);` if this is equal to false then there must be problem with the connection

Comment: Result of var_dump($ustmt) is NULL

Result of var_dump($con) is `object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL ["client_info"]=> NULL ["client_version"]=> int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL ["error_list"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["host_info"]=> NULL ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["server_info"]=> NULL ["server_version"]=> NULL ["stat"]=> NULL ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["protocol_version"]=> NULL ["thread_id"]=> NULL ["warning_count"]=> NULL }`